# Error : Internal server error in Azure AD authentication Web App deployed as docker container in Azure web App service

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, openid

I have aspnet core 2.1 web application with azure ad authentication. When I run my application locally in debugging mode everything works as expected. Whereas when I deploy my web application in azure web app service (Linux, Docker) after login it throws internal server error 500 'xxxx.azurewebsites.net can't currently handle this request.'
Below is my startup.cs and appsettings.json for reference

> {    "Authentication":  {          "ClientId": "my client Id",
> "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/My tenant Id/",
> "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:44372",
> "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",          "ClientSecret": "",          "ResponseType": "code id_token"    }  }

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Core2AadAuth.Filters;
using Core2AadAuth.Options;
using Core2AadAuth.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace Core2AadAuth
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddMvc(opts =>
      {
        opts.Filters.Add(typeof(AdalTokenAcquisitionExceptionFilter));
      }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

      //TODO: Set up Data Protection key persistence correctly for your env: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x
      //I go with defaults, which works fine in my case
      //But if you run on Azure App Service and use deployment slots, keys get swapped with the app
      //So you'll need to setup storage for keys outside the app, Key Vault and Blob Storage are some options
      services.AddDataProtection();

      //Add a strongly-typed options class to DI
      services.Configure<AuthOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Authentication"));

      services.AddScoped<ITokenCacheFactory, TokenCacheFactory>();

      services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
      {
        auth.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      })
      .AddCookie()
      .AddOpenIdConnect(opts =>
      {
        Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(opts);
        opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
          OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
          {
            n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc";
            await Task.CompletedTask;
          },
          OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
                {
                HttpRequest request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
                      //We need to also specify the redirect URL used
                      string currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, request.Path);
                      //Credentials for app itself
                      var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

                      //Construct token cache
                      ITokenCacheFactory cacheFactory = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenCacheFactory>();
                TokenCache cache = cacheFactory.CreateForUser(ctx.Principal);

                var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);

                      //Get token for Microsoft Graph API using the authorization code
                      string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
                AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                          ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(currentUri), credential, resource);

                      //Tell the OIDC middleware we got the tokens, it doesn't need to do anything
                      ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
              }
        };
      });

      services.Configure<HstsOptions>(o =>
      {
        o.IncludeSubDomains = false;
        o.Preload = false;
        o.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
      });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }
      else
      {
        //Outside dev, require HTTPS and use HSTS
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseHsts();
      }



      app.UseStaticFiles();

      app.UseAuthentication();

      app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Error after login]

> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.315827397Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.315907498Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET
> http://mwp4.azurewebsites.net/   2021-05-02T09:33:20.608016175Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.608738579Z       Route matched with {action =
> "Index", controller = "Home"}. Executing controller action with
> signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Index() on controller
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.HomeController (Core2AadAuth).
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.745331263Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.745368864Z       Executing action method
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Core2AadAuth) -
> Validation state: Valid 2021-05-02T09:33:20.755374821Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.755394921Z       Executed action method
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Core2AadAuth), returned
> result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 0.8199ms.
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.831668759Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:20.831702459Z       Executing ViewResult, running
> view Index.
>
> 2021-05-02T09:33:21.814197839Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[4]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:21.814222039Z       Executed ViewResult - view Index
> executed in 1012.1419ms. 2021-05-02T09:33:21.814531541Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:21.814560341Z       Executed action
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Core2AadAuth) in
> 1186.6101ms 2021-05-02T09:33:21.834760456Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:21.834786356Z       Request finished in 1554.1302ms
> 200 text/html; charset=utf-8 2021-05-02T09:33:24.456892780Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.456933081Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET
> http://mwp4.azurewebsites.net/Account/SignIn
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.459599695Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.459617195Z       Route matched with {action =
> "SignIn", controller = "Account"}. Executing controller action with
> signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult SignIn() on
> controller Core2AadAuth.Controllers.AccountController (Core2AadAuth).
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.459623195Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.459628095Z       Executing action method
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn (Core2AadAuth) -
> Validation state: Valid 2021-05-02T09:33:24.459632395Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.459636995Z       Executed action method
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn (Core2AadAuth),
> returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult in 0.634ms.
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.476765988Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:24.476797989Z       Executing ChallengeResult with
> authentication schemes (). 2021-05-02T09:33:25.925815616Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[12]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:25.925878418Z       AuthenticationScheme:
> OpenIdConnect was challenged. 2021-05-02T09:33:25.947421249Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:25.947478451Z       Executed action
> Core2AadAuth.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn (Core2AadAuth) in
> 1488.4947ms 2021-05-02T09:33:25.965321140Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:25.965363141Z       Request finished in 1500.8083ms
> 302
>
> 2021-05-02T09:33:29.811005026Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4dv.png)
> 2021-05-02T09:33:29.811039125Z       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST
> http://mwp4.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded 2784 2021-05-02T09:33:29.905246546Z
> [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:29.905324345Z
> '.AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect.NKdEqhMMORt61fYDDm70J3AyzqpUmgMxsYxaQfuygWI'
> cookie not found. 2021-05-02T09:33:29.906978817Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[4]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:29.906995617Z       Error from RemoteAuthentication:
> Correlation failed.. 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976640649Z
> [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976668449Z       Connection id "0HM8D9L7PD097",
> Request id "0HM8D9L7PD097:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown
> by the application. 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976674549Z System.Exception:
> An error was encountered while handling the remote login. --->
> System.Exception: Correlation failed. 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976679149Z
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976691948Z    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync() 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976696448Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976700648Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976705048Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application) 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976709248Z
> [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
> 2021-05-02T09:33:29.976713648Z       Request finished in 157.9686ms
> 500

Comment: what error do you see in your logfiles? I would also add use.Authorization() after app.UseAuthentication(); in the startup class

Comment: See my edited question for the exception I am getting in azure web app service logs. Correlation failed is the error.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of the service?

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that you do not persist the data protection key-ring across deployments. When the Data Protection API key-ring is lost, a new set of keys is generated and existing cookies will no longer be valid. The key that is used to encrypt the cookies must be the same across deployments.

I blogged earlier about one approach to this here:

- [Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault)

See also this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0)